# Synchronize the magento media folder and Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: magento, amazon-s3

We want to know the best way to synchronize the magento media folder and an Amazon S3 Bucket

Note: we don't want to use the OnePica ImageCDN

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you should be using Linux hosting (most often Linux is used to host Magento), what you could do is write an observer hook it `catalog_product_prepare_save` event. This will hook your app to an event when the product is saved. On the save of product you can execute the rsync command `rsync options source destination` which will sync your media folder and S3.

You can use exec("rsync options source destination") in your observer.php to trigger the sync from application.

You may have a better look at rsync function [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).